# Ionic not importing ngx-mathjax module

Tags: angular, import, ionic3, mathjax

I'm trying to install Mathjax in an ionic app using ngx-mathjax
( https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-mathjax )

I imported the module in app.module.ts and pasted the config method as shown. I added  tags in the component I want to use Mathjax in, but the "import MathJaxModule" line is failing.

The given import statement fails with runtime error: "Cannot find module "./src/app/math-jax/math-jax.module". VSCode underlines it in red actually.

I've tried a few different paths:

`'ngx-mathjax/src/app/math-jax/math-jax.module';`

`'../../node_modules/ngx-mathjax/src/app/math-jax/math-jax.module';`

and I get the same error just with the paths changed. I'm not sure if the package has problems or I'm just an idiot. I'm assuming the latter.

Here's the relevant code from my app.module.ts file:

```
import {MathJaxModule} from './src/app/math-jax/math-jax.module';


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    MathJaxModule.config({
      version: '2.7.5',
      config: 'TeX-AMS_HTML',
      hostname: 'cdnjs.cloudflare.com'
    })
  ],
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HeaderComponent,
    ...pages,
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    ...pages,
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
    CourseService,
    StorageService,
    AppRate
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Here's my HTML

```html
  <div mathjax>
$$
f\\left(-2\\right)
$$
</div>
```

Any help with the issue would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Import it like this

```
import { MathJaxModule } from 'ngx-mathjax';
```